# how to pass input value from child to parent in functional componenent

Tags: reactjs

How do I pass input ref values from Child.js to Parent.js in functional component? I have tried using `forwardRef` but it can only pass one value, what I need is passing multiple input values from Child.js to Parent.js

`Child.js`

```
export default function Child() {
  const id1 = useRef('')
  const id2 = useRef('')

  return (
            <>
                <input type="text" id="id1" ref={id1} />
                <label for="id1"> ID 1</label>

                <input type="text" id="id2" ref={id2} />
                <label for="id2"> ID 2</label>
            </>
        )
}
```

`Parent.js`

```
export default function Parent() {
  function onSubmit() {
    console.log(## I WANT REF ID1 AND ID2 FROM CHILD.JS VALUE HERE ##)
 }

  return ( <>
    <Child />

    <button onClick={onSubmit}>
      Submit
    </button>
  </>)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Child.js**

```
export default function Child(props) {
  const id1 = useRef('')
  const id2 = useRef('')

  props.func('My name is Dean Winchester & this is my brother Sammie');

  return (
            <>
                <input type="text" id="id1" ref={id1} />
                <label for="id1"> ID 1</label>

                <input type="text" id="id2" ref={id2} />
                <label for="id2"> ID 2</label>
            </>
        )
}
```

**parent.js**

```
export default function Parent() {
  function onSubmit() {
    console.log(## I WANT REF ID1 AND ID2 FROM CHILD.JS VALUE HERE ##)
 }

    const pull_data = (data) => {
    console.log(data); // LOGS DATA FROM CHILD (My name is Dean Winchester... &)
  }

  return ( <>
    <Child func={pull_data} />

    <button onClick={onSubmit}>
      Submit
    </button>
  </>)
}
```

Comment: I have put `onChange={() => { props.func(id1.current.value) }}` under `input id1`, however in my `Parent.js`, is there any other way to pull the data other than giving it a state so when I click on the Submit button it will console.log the data?

Comment: @Gravity you have to use state for store the value. Here is the codesandbox link you can refer https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-snyder-logm0

Answer (score 0):

Pass a callback to `Child` and call it in `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    onRefLoad(id1, id2);
}, [])
```

and save it to some kind of state in `Parent` to be able to use it in `onSubmit`

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options here, depending on your situation. For forms easiest solution would be to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) interface to get all values in form. You set up your `onSubmit` handler on form and when form will be submitted via default browser methods (pressing Enter/Return in field or pressing submit button), you can get form from event and build FormData object:

```js
// parent
function Form({ children }) {
  function handleSubmit(event) {
    // disable page reload and actual submitting of form if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData(event.target);
  }
  return (
    <form id="my-form-id" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {children}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

However it might not work properly, if you use some non standard elements. In this case you can set up some kind of `onChange` handler to get data from child and save it in parent state. When button will be pressed you will get data from local (in parent) state and use it.

Comment: Thank you for replying, however since I will have a lot more than just one `Child.js`, I will much prefer having all the input under `Child.js` itself and having a button instead in my `Parent.js` just to make things more organize

Comment: I don't see how this don't fit with approach I suggest. Basically, all fields that are inside form tag will have their values inside FormData object created from that form. You can replace `{children}` from props with `<Child/>` component and result will be same. This approach worked even before react was created, so it is somewhat universal in web.